# Seperate file name from path glob()

Tags: php

How do I get only the file name instead of the path + file name?

```
foreach(glob('./item/*.txt') as $filename){
   echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: If you `chdir()` to move into the specific directory before calling `glob()`, then you'll get no path in your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename($filename)` to get the filename of the file. Check the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php